# Cómo obtener qué botón se presionó primero, cuál segundo, cuál tercero

Tags: android, android-studio, botón, textview

Hola buenos días cómo están? espero que bien.
Estoy desarrollando una app donde en una parte de esta tengo 6 botones y 6 textviews. La idea es obtener los textos de esos 6 botones(getText().toString()); para que luego sean visualizados en los textViews.

Tengo 6 botones boton1, boton2,boton3,boton4,boton5,boton6.

Y 6 TextViews
text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6

La idea es que el primer botón que sea pulsado aparezca en el text1, sin importar si fue el 1,2,3,4,5,o 6. El segundo botón que sea pulsado en el sin importar si fue el 1, el 5, el 6, el 2, el 3 o el 4 en el text2, el tercer botón en el text3, etc.

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora

```
package com.**.**;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class quiz extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button opcion1;
    private Button opcion2;
    private Button opcion3;
    private Button opcion4;
    private Button opcion5;
    private Button opcion6;

    private TextView text0;
    private TextView text1;
    private TextView text2;
    private TextView text3;
    private TextView text4;
    private TextView text5;
    private TextView text6;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    text0 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text0);
    text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
    text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
    text4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text4);
    text5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text5);
    text6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text6);

    opcion1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion1);
    opcion2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion2);
    opcion3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion3);
    opcion4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion4);
    opcion5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion5);
    opcion6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcion6);


    opcion1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        Button opcion1 = (Button)view;
        String textButton = opcion1.getText().toString();
     text0.setText(textButton);

        //writeTextView();
    }

});


opcion2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion2 = (Button)view;
        String textButton2 = opcion2.getText().toString();
        text2.setText(textButton2);
    }
});

opcion3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion3 = (Button)view;
        String textButton3 = opcion3.getText().toString();
        text3.setText(textButton3);
    }
});

opcion4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion4 = (Button)view;
        String textButton4 = opcion4.getText().toString();
        text4.setText(textButton4);
    }
});

opcion5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion5 = (Button)view;
        String textButton5 = opcion5.getText().toString();
        text5.setText(textButton5);
    }
});

opcion6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button opcion6 = (Button)view;
        String textButton6 = opcion6.getText().toString();
        text6.setText(textButton6);
    }
});

}
```

}

El problema es que con este código cuando presiono el buton1, setea el texto en el textview 1, el buton 2, en el text2, el buton 3 en el text3, etc. Y yo necesito que el primer botón que sea apretado sin importar cual es setee el texto en el textview1, el segundo boton que sea apretado sin importar cualsea en el textview2, etc.

Gracias y espero puedan ayudarme ! Mauro

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que los TextView no tienen texto al inicio, podria verificar uno por uno su condicion y si no tienen texto setearle el valor:

```
 public void seterTexto(String textButtom) {
    TextView text1;
    if (text1.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        text1.setText(textButtom);

    } else if (text2.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        text2.setText(textButtom);

    }//aqui evaluar los demas textos

}
```

y el metodo lo usarias al presionar el boton:

```
 opcion6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Button opcion6 = (Button)view;
    String textButton6 = opcion6.getText().toString();
    seterTexto(textButton6);
   }
});
```

El metodo se repite en cada boton que presionas